stb_image не отображает текстуру
я пишу программу используя GLFW как оболочку OpenGL и stb_image.h для загрузки изображений
но изображения по какой то причине не выводится
вот код:
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#include "shaderClass.h"
#include "VAO.h"
#include "VBO.h"
#include "EBO.h"

GLfloat vertices[] =
{
     -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
     -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f, 0.f
};

GLuint indices[] =
{
    0, 2, 1,
    0, 3, 2
};

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "3D anatomy", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    gladLoadGL();
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);

    Shader shaderProgram("default.vert", "default.frag");

    VAO VAO1;
    VAO1.Bind();

    VBO VBO1(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    EBO EBO1(indices, sizeof(indices));

    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    VAO1.Unbind();
    VBO1.Unbind();
    EBO1.Unbind();

    GLuint uniID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "scale");

    int widthImg, heightImg, numColCh;
    unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load("dog.png", &widthImg, &heightImg, &numColCh, 0);

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, widthImg, heightImg, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    stbi_image_free(bytes);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLuint tex0Uni = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "tex0");

    shaderProgram.Activate();
    glUniform1i(tex0Uni, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shaderProgram.Activate();
        glUniform1f(uniID, 0.5f);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        VAO1.Bind();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    VAO1.Delete();
    VBO1.Delete();
    EBO1.Delete();
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
    shaderProgram.Delete();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


Для начала стоит проверить, загрузилась ли картинка.
